# Circular dependency when adding reference (Delegates)

Tags: c#, circular-dependency

Basically I have 2 projects, a form and a user control.

I need both of them to be in different projects but the form need to refer to the user control as it is using the user control. And the user control will need to refer to the form as it is using one of the form class. When I add the second one because it need the , VS will complain circular dependency which is understandable. How do I solve this?

Comment: Can you abstract out the non-UI classes from the Forms project and create a DLL?

Comment: Create a third project that contains everything *both* the form and the user control need.  You'll never get your builds to work correctly without doing that.

Answer (score 2):

Logically the form should depend on the user control. You could create an interface to replace the form within the user control project, and then have the form implement that interface.

Example user control project;

```
public interface IForm
{
    string MyString { get; }
}

public class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
     public IForm Form { get; set; }

     private void ShowMyString()
     {
          String myString = Form.MyString;
          ...
     }
}
```

Example Form project

```
public class MyForm : Form, IForm
{
    public MYString { get "My String Value"; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the root cause of your problem is that you haven't separated your concerns between the form and the control properly.

Since you have a (somewhat generic) control, it shouldn't depend on the form. All of the logic of the control should reside within the control itself. The form should only black-box consume the control: add it, set public fields, call public methods, etc. anything else is a violation of encapsulation.

Sometimes, controls may need to know things about *their parent form*. In this case, I would suggest something as simple as adding a `Parent` field to the child control.

if you need something more specific from the form, you can always add an interface; the interface should only list those things that the control needs from the form. For example, if you need the size, you can add:

```
public interface IControlParent {
  int Width { get; }
  int Height { get; }
}
```

This way, you clearly see the dependencies (what the control needs from the parent), and if the parent type/contract changes, you don't need to do as much to change your control class.

Answer (score 0):

You must sepárate your code, its never a good idea to have a reference to an application assembly, if you try to reuse it in the future, the applications exe should go with the control.

So, take the class from the form project and move it to the control project or create a library project, put the class on it and reference it from your control and your app projects.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an event (delegate). Let's assume that inside your form project you created one class: Form1. And inside user control you defined UserControl1.
UserControl1 needs to instantiate and call a method from Form1:

```
public class Form1
{
    public void Execute(string sMessage)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(sMessage);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

UserControl1:

```
public class UserControl
{
    public Func<object, object> oDel = null;

    public void Execute()
    {
        oDel?.Invoke("HELLO WORLD!");
    }
}
```

And from the class that instantiate UserControl, let's call it ParentClass:

```
public class ParentClass
{
    public void Execute()
    {
        UserControl oUserControl = new UserControl();
        oUserControl.oDel = Form1Action;
        oUserControl.Execute();
    }

    public object Form1Action(object obj)
    {
        string sObj = Convert.ToString(obj);

        Form1 oForm = new Form1();
        oForm.Execute(sObj);

        return null;
    }
}
```

This approach gives the responsibility of handling an event to the high level class.